# Why I cannot let EXPLAIN update statements?

Tags: mysql, update, debugging, explain

I can imagine that it's actually more important to explain SELECT statements, but I wonder why there's no possibility to use EXPLAIN on UPDATEs/INSERTs.  I may use a WHERE-statement in an UPDATE where indexes are being used (I guess?), it should be possible to see if they are actually used.  Additionally, in the case of using a SELECT-statement inside an UPDATE, I also cannot use explain for this part without getting a syntax error.
Did I misunderstand something about the processes on UPDATEs and INSERTs?  How else can I else debug those statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL currently doesn't support this (unlike nearly all other DBMS).

I think this will be in 5.6 but I'm not entirely sure.

I don't think there is any workaround for that (except upgrading to a DBMS that does support this)

Comment: It is in [MySQL 5.6 (still in dev.)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html)

Comment: @ypercube: thanks for the confirmation. I just heard that it's finally going to come but wasn't sure in which version.

Comment: I have been mistakenly thinking it was added in MariaDB but it's only in MySQL 5.6

Comment: Thanks. It seems 5.6 turns out to be a really desirable version, thinking of fulltext-search in InnoDB and now the fact about the explain...it's just curious why quite essential features (in my opinion) aren't implemented yet.

Comment: @32bitfloat: well 5.6 still doesn't catch up with modern SQL features like recursive queries, windowing functions or simply expression based indexes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I am not familiar with other DBMS (and SQL Standard itself), which one would achieve this?

Comment: @32bitfloat: any of the commercial ones and PostgreSQL in the OpenSource league.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Many thanks, I'll try PostgreSQL in the near future.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html
MySQL 5.6 has so many good features but delaying release will not help much. I think they should plan GA ASAP .. We are waiting.